# How to create a resizable table in html with scrollbars using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, scrollbar, resizable

I want to create a table in HTML which is having resizable columns. I also want scrollbars to table but header of table should remain fixed while scrolling.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[www.tablefixedheader.com](http://www.tablefixedheader.com/documentation/)

> > Just create a basic valid HTML  like the example below. But note that the hierarchy must be :
>
> ```
>  - table > thead > tr > th
>  - table > tbody > tr > td
> ```

[Example for re-sizable cols](http://www.tablefixedheader.com/fullpagedemo/#ex_4)

```
    $('#4').fixheadertable({ 
    caption     : 'My employees', 
    colratio    : [50, 150, 150, 150, 220, 150], 
    height      : 200, 
    width       : 800, 
    zebra       : true,
    resizeCol   : true,
    minColWidth : 50 
});
```

Comment: Follow the link i have given in the answer! However here is the home page link again.  [link]http://www.tablefixedheader.com/

Comment: Github page: [link]https://benjaminleouzon@github.com/benjaminleouzon/tablefixedheader

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is your solution. see the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VBH8a/) on jsfiddle. if you want to load data from server, set `savedStateLoad: true`. otherwise ignore the ajax part, in your case, just set `savedStateLoad: false`

the original source of the code is [here](http://reconstrukt.com), thanks to them.